# can anyone explain how backBarButtonItem Action is overrided?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have asked this question sometime back. But havent got a solution yet,
Here is my scenario.

```
//RootViewController.m
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view1 Animated:YES];
```

Here is View1.m

```
UIBarButtonItem *back_of_view2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back to RootViewfromview2"
target:self
action:@selector(backClicked:)];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
```

And here is the backClicked method: (still in view1.m)

```
-(void)backClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)back_of_view2
{
[self.navigationController popToRootViewController Animated:YES]
}
```

I am able to get the back button in view2 as "back to RootViewfromview2" but the action backClicked is not getting called and when I click on back, I am getting the view1 , which is the default action.
But, when I set the leftBarButtonItem in view2.m i.e

```
UIBarButtonItem *backtoOne = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"JumptorootView" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(someMethod:)];

-(void)someMethod:(UIBarButtonItem *)backtoOne  
{
[self.navigationController popToRootViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Now.., if i use leftBarButtonItem..,Everthing works fine, but I wont get the back Arrow..

Comment: You can't, because custom actions in `backBarButtomItem` never gets called. See this: http://adrianhosey.blogspot.com.es/2009/06/why-wont-my-backbarbuttonitem-use-its.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the image like the back button shown in default navigation bar.If you override the back button on navigation bar , as you are doing in above code , then you will not get the default back button, instead create an image like  a back button and assign that image to your left bar button item.

Hope it helps.......

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this situation is for the `viewController2` to send `viewController1` a message via a delegate protocol when it's about to be popped off the navigation stack. In this sample, I'm assuming `viewController2` is an instance of class `DetailViewController`.

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)detailViewControllerDidFinish:(DetailViewController *)detailViewController
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if ([self isMovingFromParentViewController]) {
        [self.delegate detailViewControllerDidFinish:self];
    }
}

@end
```